# Create Hive ORC table from ORC files of other server

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

we have 2 clusters one Map R and another our own. We want created new setup in our own hardware using the Map R data.

1. I have copied all the orc files from the Map R cluster and followed the same folder structure
2. Created a orc formatted table with location of #1
3. then executed this command "MSCK REPAIR TABLE <>"

above steps passed without error, but when i query the partitions then job fails with  below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer size too small. size = 262144 needed = 4958903
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.InStream$CompressedStream.readHeader(InStream.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.InStream$CompressedStream.read(InStream.java:238)
```

Can some one tell me can we create HIVE ORC partition tables directly from the orc files?

My storage is Azure data lake.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you want to copy all orc files from a cluster to another and load these orc files as a hive table.

For doing it, please just try to follow the command below to create external table for loading orcfile data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXSISTS <table name> (<column_name column_type>, ...)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
    STORED AS ORC 
    LOCATION '<orcfile path>'
```

If not aware of the columns list of an orc file, you can refer to the Hive manual [`ORC File Dump Utility`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility) to print the ORC file metadata in JSON format via `hive --orcfiledump -j -p <location-of-orc-file-or-directory>`.

Comment: Yes.  Your understanding is correct. But i am not copying  by "hadoop distcp " command. Because my new storage account is Azure Data lake. When i execute small data set count(*) i see mapper %age like above.

Comment: ERROR : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer size too small. size = 262144 needed = 4958903    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.InStream.addOneCompressionBuffer(InStream.java:780)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.InStream.uncompressStream(InStream.java:628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.EncodedReaderImpl.readEncodedColumns(EncodedReaderImpl.java:309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.io.encoded.OrcEncodedDataReader.callInternal(OrcEncodedDataReader.java:278)

Comment: @Harish Please try to refer to the Hive issue [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10161) to resolve it.